# Sum by row with reference to other cell values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I have a vague memory doing this a year back and want to repeat the function. I want to use B2 as a reference to my formula, where my formula is reading in values from another tab and can be expanded by dragging and dropping. My picture is trying to illustrate the issue,

The pink cells are not using the reference cell B2, heading Formula 1 show the formula in column B.

The blue cells is what I have now, column D is the results from the formula in column E (row by row). Here I have created the formula in cell D4 and then dragged it down to D6.

The green cell is what I want to achieve, note the discrepancy marked in red.

I want to be able to write the formula in cell D4 and then drag it down to D6. How can this be done without adding new columns.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
=INDIRECT("'" & $B$2 & "'!C" & ROW())
```

I added `''` around the sheet name in case the sheet name in B2 contains spaces.

Comment: The explanation for the `"'"` was a good one, you may write it in the post.